# Four ones and four zeros

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Which is the smallest natural number that can not be expressed in base 2 with precisely four ones and four zeros using the four basic arithmetic operations, exponentiation, concatenation, brackets, fractions, factorials (including double factorials), fractional points (both with or without leading zeros, e.g. 0.0001111 or .00110011), and square roots?

(This question arose during a discussion with participants in the Soacha (Colombia) 2023 Math Circle.)

[499 and the Gamma Function](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120254/499-and-the-gamma-function)

Comment: I am looking for the smallest positive integer not so expressible. I have a possible candidate, but perhaps others can do better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144618/discussion-between-bernardo-recaman-santos-and-weather-vane).

Comment: "Concatenation of the original digits" is a much better way of putting it, unless you really mean we can take any intermediate result and concatenate it with other stuff.

Comment: Double factorial is extensible - where do we stand on triple factorial, quadruple factorial, et cetera?

Comment: No, not allowed.

Comment: Think prime numbers

Comment: The current least candidate for the actual answer in the accepted answer is disqualified if, for example, binary fractions such as .1 can be represented by "." with (the result of) "0!" concatenated, where this generated "1" does not count against the four given ones. This possible interpretation and example emphasize the importance of the comment of @Bass (which I upvoted earlier). For clarity (for future readers), the question should explicitly say what exactly can be concatenated. It would take a lot of looking/time to see what everyone is actually (not) doing in each answer otherwise.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos Out of curiosity, would you mind sharing what your original possible candidate was? Now that you have accepted an answer?

Comment: MountainEucalyptus: Ashamed to say, a certain number in the 80's!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit: I upgraded the solver to include the pattern `.1^-x`. It can now solve more numbers.

I wrote a computer program to automatically search for solutions. My program has found solutions for most integers from 0 to 900, listed below. Here are the ten smallest integers it couldn't find solutions for (when I originally posted this):

> $462 = ((100!!)!!+0!)/(0!-1/11!)$
>  $462 = (11!)!-.1^{-100!!}-0!-0!$
>  $499 = ((11!)!!+0!+0!)^{(0!+.1)}/\sqrt{.1} - 0!$ (loopy walt)
>  $501 = ((11!)!!+0!+0!)^{(0!+.1)}/\sqrt{.1} + 0!$ (loopy walt)
>  $507 = .1^{-100!!-0!}-101$
>  $549 = ((0!+0!+0!)!+(11!)!*.1)*(0!+.1)$ (Weather Vane)
>  $607 = ?$
>  $652 = ?$
>  $653 = ?$
>  $787 = ?$
>  $795 = (100!!-.1)*((11!+0!)!!+0!)$ (Weather Vane)

As a result, the smallest unsolved integer is currently

> $607$

---

Here's it's full output for all integers from 0 to 900. I stopped at 900 due to the character limit. Solutions are ordered by fewest bits used, tiebroken by fewest ones used. `s` represents square root.

```
0: 0
1: 0!
2: 0!+0!
3: 11
4: 100
5: 101
6: 11!
7: 11!+0!
8: 100!!
9: 100!!+0!
10: 1010
11: s(101!+0!)
12: (11!)/.1
13: 1101
14: 101!!-(0!)
15: 101!!
16: .01^-(0!+0!)
17: .01^-(0!+0!)+0!
18: (11!)*11
19: s(((11!)!)*.1+0!)
20: 10100
21: 10101
22: 100!-(0!)-(0!)
23: 100!-(0!)
24: 100!
25: 100!+0!
26: 100!+0!+0!
27: 11^11
28: 11100
29: (101!!)/.1-(0!)
30: (101!!)/.1
31: .1^-101-(0!)
32: .1^-101
33: .1^-101+0!
34: 100010
35: (11!)^(0!+0!)-(0!)
36: (11!)^(0!+0!)
37: (11!)^(0!+0!)+0!
38: s(((11!)!+0!+0!)/.1)
39: 100!+101!!
40: (11!)!!-(100!!)
41: (11!)!!-(11!+0!)
42: (11!)!!-(11!)
43: (11!)!!-101
44: (11!)!!-100
45: (11!)!!-11
46: (11!)!!-(0!+0!)
47: (11!)!!-(0!)
48: (11!)!!
49: (11!)!!+0!
50: (11!)!!+0!+0!
51: (11!)!!+11
52: (11!)!!+100
53: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)*.1
54: (11!)!!+11!
55: (11!)!!+11!+0!
56: (11!)!!+100!!
57: (11!+0!)!!-((11!)!!)
58: (101!)*.1-(0!+0!)
59: (101!)*.1-(0!)
60: (101!)*.1
61: (101!)*.1+0!
62: .1^-(11!)-(0!+0!)
63: .1^-(11!)-(0!)
64: .1^-(11!)
65: .1^-(11!)+0!
66: .1^-(11!)+0!+0!
67: .1^-(11!)+0!+0!+0!
68: .1^-(11!)+100
69: s((11!+0!)!+0!)-(0!+0!)
70: s((11!+0!)!+0!)-(0!)
71: s((11!+0!)!+0!)
72: ((11!)!!)*1.1
73: ((11!)!!)*1.1+0!
74: ((11!)^(0!+0!)+0!)/.1
75: (100!+0!)*11
76: (s(((11!)!)*.1+0!))/.01
77: s((11!+0!)!+0!)+11!
78: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!))*.11
79: (101!)/1.1-(0!)
80: (101!)/1.1
81: 11^100
82: 11^100+0!
83: 11^100+0!+0!
84: ((11!)!!-((0!+0!+0!)!))/.1
85: ((11!)!!-((0!+0!+0!)!))/.1+0!
86: ((11!)!!+0!-((0!+0!+0!)!))/.1
87: .1^-(11!)+100!-(0!)
88: .1^-(11!)+100!
89: ((11!)!)/(100!!)-(0!)
90: ((11!)!)/(100!!)
91: ((11!)!)/(100!!)+0!
92: ((11!)!!-(0!+0!))/.1
93: ((11!)!!-(0!))/.1-(0!)
94: ((11!)!!-(0!))/.1
95: ((11!)!!)/.1-(0!)
96: ((11!)!!)/.1
97: ((11!)!!)/.1+0!
98: ((11!)!!+0!)/.1
99: ((11!)!!+0!)/.1+0!
100: ((11!)!!+0!+0!)/.1
101: (11!+0!)!!-100
102: (11!+0!)!!-11
103: (11!+0!)!!-(0!+0!)
104: (11!+0!)!!-(0!)
105: (11!+0!)!!
106: (11!+0!)!!+0!
107: (11!+0!)!!+0!+0!
108: (11!+0!)!!+11
109: (11!+0!)!!+100
110: (11!+0!)!!+101
111: (11!+0!)!!+11!
112: 101!-(100!!)
113: (11!+0!)!!+100!!
114: 101!-(11!)
115: 101!-101
116: 101!-100
117: 101!-11
118: 101!-(0!)-(0!)
119: 101!-(0!)
120: 101!
121: 101!+0!
122: 101!+0!+0!
123: 101!+11
124: 101!+100
125: 101^11
126: 101!+11!
127: .1^-(11!+0!)-(0!)
128: .1^-(11!+0!)
129: .1^-(11!+0!)+0!
130: (.1^-(11!)+0!)/.1
131: (.1^-(11!)+0!)/.1+0!
132: (.1^-(11!)+0!+0!)/.1
133: (.1^-(11!)+0!+0!)/.1+0!
134: .1^-(11!+0!)+(0!+0!+0!)!
135: 101!+101!!
136: 101!+.01^-(0!+0!)
137: (100!-(0!))*(11!)-(0!)
138: (100!-(0!))*(11!)
139: ((11!+0!)!!)/.11-(0!)
140: ((11!+0!)!!)/.11
141: ((11!)!!-(0!))*11
142: (s((11!+0!)!+0!))/.1
143: ((11!)!!)*11-(0!)
144: ((11!)!!)*11
145: ((11!)!!)*11+0!
146: ((11!)!!)*11+0!+0!
147: ((11!)!!+0!)*11
148: ((11!)!!+0!)*11+0!
149: (100!+0!)*(11!)-(0!)
150: (100!+0!)*(11!)
151: (100!+0!)*(11!)+0!
152: (11!+0!)!!+(11!)!!-(0!)
153: (11!+0!)!!+(11!)!!
154: (11!+0!)!!+(11!)!!+0!
155: (11!+0!)!!+(11!)!!+0!+0!
156: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!))*1.1
157: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!))*1.1+0!
158: (101!)/.11-(0!+0!)
159: (101!)/.11-(0!)
160: (101!)/.11
161: (101!)/.11+0!
162: (11^100)/.1
163: (11^100)/.1+0!
164: (11^100+0!)/.1
165: (101!!)*(s(101!+0!))
166: 101!-(0!)-(0!)+(11!)!!
167: 101!-(0!)+(11!)!!
168: 101!+(11!)!!
169: 1101^(0!+0!)
170: 1101^(0!+0!)+0!
171: 1101^10+0!+0!
172: ((11!)!)*.01-(100!!)
173: ((11!)!)*.01-(100!!-(0!))
174: ((11!)!)*.01-((0!+0!+0!)!)
175: (100!+0!)*(11!+0!)
176: .1^-(11!+0!)+((0!+0!+0!)!)!!
177: ((11!)!)*.01-(0!+0!+0!)
178: ((11!)!)*.01-(0!+0!)
179: ((11!)!)*.01-(0!)
180: ((11!)!)*.01
181: ((11!)!)*.01+0!
182: ((11!)!)*.01+0!+0!
183: ((11!)!)*.01+0!+0!+0!
184: ((11!)!!-(0!+0!))/.01
185: ((11!)!!-(0!+0!))/.01+0!
186: ((100!!)!!)*.1-(11!)
187: ((11!)!!-(0!))/.01-(0!)
188: ((11!)!!-(0!))/.01
189: ((11!)!!-(0!))/.01+0!
190: (((11!)!!)/.1-(0!))/.1
191: ((100!!)!!)*.1-(0!)
192: ((100!!)!!)*.1
193: ((100!!)!!)*.1+0!
194: (((11!)!!)/.1+0!)/.1
195: ((11!)!!+0!)/.01-(0!)
196: ((11!)!!+0!)/.01
197: ((11!)!!+0!)/.01+0!
198: ((100!!)!!)*.1+11!
199: s((100!!)!-((11!)!)+0!)
200: ((11!)!!+0!+0!)/.01
201: ((11!)!!+0!+0!)/.01+0!
202: ((11!+0!)!!-100)/.1
203: ((11!)!)*.01+100!-(0!)
204: ((100!!)!!+100!)*.1
205: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!+0!))/.1-(0!)
206: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!+0!))/.1
207: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!))/.1-(0!)
208: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!))/.1
209: ((11!+0!)!!)/.1-(0!)
210: ((11!+0!)!!)/.1
211: ((11!+0!)!!)/.1+0!
212: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)/.1
213: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)/.1+0!
214: ((11!+0!)!!+0!+0!)/.1
215: (11!)^11-(0!)
216: (11!)^11
217: (11!)^11+0!
218: (11!)^11+0!+0!
219: (11!)^11+0!+0!+0!
220: ((100!!)!!+0!)/1.11
221: (101!!)^10-100
222: ((11!+0!)!!+(0!+0!+0!)!)/.1
223: (101!!)^10-(0!+0!)
224: (101!!)^(0!+0!)-(0!)
225: (101!!)^(0!+0!)
226: (101!!)^(0!+0!)+0!
227: (101!!)^10+0!+0!
228: (101!-((0!+0!+0!)!))/.1
229: (101!!)^10+100
230: ((11!)!!-(0!+0!))*101
231: (101!!)^(0!+0!)+11!
232: .1^-(100!!)-(100!)
233: (101!!)^10+100!!
234: (101!-(0!)-(0!+0!))/.1
235: ((11!)!!-(0!))*101
236: (101!-(0!)-(0!))/.1
237: (101!-(0!))/.1-(0!)
238: (101!-(0!))/.1
239: (101!)/.1-(0!)
240: (101!)/.1
241: (101!)/.1+0!
242: (101!+0!)/.1
243: 11^101
244: (101!+0!+0!)/.1
245: ((11!)!!+0!)*101
246: (101!+0!+0!+0!)/.1
247: (101!)/.1+100!!-(0!)
248: .1^-(100!!)-(100!!)
249: .1^-(100!!)-(11!+0!)
250: .1^-(100!!)-(11!)
251: .1^-(100!!)-101
252: (.1^-(11!)-(0!))/.01
253: .1^-(100!!)-11
254: .1^-(100!!)-(0!+0!)
255: .1^-(100!!)-(0!)
256: .1^-(100!!)
257: .1^-(100!!)+0!
258: .1^-(100!!)+0!+0!
259: .1^-(100!!)+11
260: (.1^-(11!)+0!)/.01
261: .1^-(100!!)+101
262: .1^-(100!!)+11!
263: (100!!)!!-(101!+0!)
264: (100!!)!!-(101!)
265: (100!!)!!-(101!-(0!))
266: .1^-(100!!)+1010
267: .1^-(100!!)+s(101!+0!)
268: ((11!)!)*.011-(0!+0!)
269: ((11!)!)*.011-(0!)
270: ((11!)!)*.011
271: ((11!)!)*.011+0!
272: ((11!)!)*.011+0!+0!
273: (101!!)^(0!+0!)+(11!)!!
274: (101!!)^(0!+0!)+(11!)!!+0!
275: ((11!)!!-(0!+0!))*(11!)-(0!)
276: ((11!)!!-(0!+0!))*(11!)
277: ((11!)!!-(0!+0!))*(11!)+0!
278: (100!!)!!-(0!)-((11!+0!)!!)
279: (100!!)!!-((11!+0!)!!)
280: ((11!+0!)!!)/.011
281: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(11!)-(0!)
282: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(11!)
283: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(11!)+0!
284: (s((11!+0!)!+0!))/.01
285: (((11!)!!)/.1-(0!))*(0!+0!+0!)
286: ((11!)!!)*(11!)-(0!+0!)
287: ((11!)!!)*(11!)-(0!)
288: ((11!)!!)*(11!)
289: ((11!)!!)*(11!)+0!
290: ((11!)!!)*(11!)+0!+0!
291: (((11!)!!)/.1+0!)*(0!+0!+0!)
292: ((11!)!!+0!)*(11!)-(0!+0!)
293: ((11!)!!+0!)*(11!)-(0!)
294: ((11!)!!+0!)*(11!)
295: ((11!)!!+0!)*(11!)+0!
296: ((11!)!!+0!)*(11!)+0!+0!
297: ((100!!)!!)*.1+(11!+0!)!!
298: (101!)*10.1-(0!+0!)
299: (101!)*10.1-(0!)
300: (101!)*10.1
301: (101!)*10.1+0!
302: (101!)*10.1+0!+0!
303: .1^-(100!!)-(0!)+(11!)!!
304: .1^-(100!!)+(11!)!!
305: .1^-(100!!)+(11!)!!+0!
306: ((11!+0!)!!+((0!+0!+0!)!)!!)/.1
307: ((100!!)!!+1)/1.01-(0!)
308: ((100!!)!!+0!)/1.01
309: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!+0!))*11
310: ((11!)!)/(0!+0!)-((11!)!!+0!+0!)
311: ((11!)!)*.1-(0!)-(((0!+0!+0!)!)!!)
312: ((11!)!)*.1-(((0!+0!+0!)!)!!)
313: ((11!)!)*.1+0!-(((0!+0!+0!)!)!!)
314: ((11!+0!)!!)*11-(0!)
315: ((11!+0!)!!)*11
316: ((11!+0!)!!)*11+0!
317: ((11!+0!)!!)*11+0!+0!
318: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)*11
319: (101!)/.011-(0!)
320: (101!)/.011
321: (101!)/.011+0!
322: ((11!)!!-(0!+0!))*(11!+0!)
323: ((11!)*11)^(0!+0!)-(0!)
324: ((11!)*11)^(0!+0!)
325: ((11!)*11)^(0!+0!)+0!
326: ((11!)*11)^(0!+0!)+0!+0!
327: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(11!+0!)-(0!+0!)
328: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(11!+0!)-(0!)
329: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(11!+0!)
330: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(11!+0!)+0!
331: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(11!+0!)+0!+0!
332: (100!!)!!-((11!)!!)-100
333: ((11!)!!)*(11!+0!)-(0!+0!+0!)
334: (100!!)!!-((11!)!!)-(0!+0!)
335: (100!!)!!-((11!)!!)-(0!)
336: (100!!)!!-((11!)!!)
337: (100!!)!!-((11!)!!)+0!
338: (100!!)!!-((11!)!!)+0!+0!
339: ((11!)!!)*(11!+0!)+0!+0!+0!
340: (.1^-(100!!)-(0!))/.11
341: (11!+0!)^11-(0!+0!)
342: (11!+0!)^11-(0!)
343: (11!+0!)^11
344: (11!+0!)^11+0!
345: (100!-(0!))*(101!!)
346: (11!+0!)^11+0!+0!+0!
347: ((11!)!-(100!))*.1-(0!)
348: ((11!)!-(100!))*.1
349: ((11!)!-(100!))*.1+0!
350: ((11!)!!+0!+0!)*(11!+0!)
351: ((11!)!)*.1-(100!!+0!)
352: ((11!)!)*.1-(100!!)
353: ((11!)!)*.1-(0!)-((0!+0!+0!)!)
354: ((11!)!)*.1-((0!+0!+0!)!)
355: ((11!)!)*.1+0!-((0!+0!+0!)!)
356: ((11!)!)*.1-100
357: ((11!)!)*.1-(0!+0!+0!)
358: ((11!)!)*.1-(0!+0!)
359: ((11!)!)*.1-(0!)
360: ((11!)!)*.1
361: ((11!)!)*.1+0!
362: ((11!)!)*.1+0!+0!
363: ((11!)!)*.1+0!+0!+0!
364: ((11!)!)*.1+100
365: ((11!)!)*.1-(0!)+(0!+0!+0!)!
366: ((11!)!)*.1+(0!+0!+0!)!
367: ((11!)!)*.1+0!+(0!+0!+0!)!
368: ((11!)!)*.1+100!!
369: (100!!)!!-(101!!)
370: (100!!)!!-(101!!-(0!))
371: (100!!)!!-1101
372: (100!!)!!-((11!)/.1)
373: (100!!)!!-(s(101!+0!))
374: (100!!)!!-1010
375: (100!+0!)*(101!!)
376: (100!!)!!-(100!!)
377: (100!!)!!-(11!+0!)
378: (100!!)!!-(11!)
379: (100!!)!!-101
380: (100!!)!!-100
381: (100!!)!!-11
382: (100!!)!!-(0!+0!)
383: (100!!)!!-(0!)
384: (100!!)!!
385: (100!!)!!+0!
386: (100!!)!!+0!+0!
387: (100!!)!!+11
388: (100!!)!!+100
389: (100!!)!!+101
390: (100!!)!!+11!
391: (100!!)!!+11!+0!
392: (100!!)!!+100!!
393: (100!!)!!+1001
394: (100!!)!!+1010
395: (100!!)!!+s(101!+0!)
396: (100!!)!!+(11!)/.1
397: (100!!)!!+1101
398: (100!!)!!+101!!-(0!)
399: (100!!)!!+101!!
400: 10100^10
401: 10100^10+1
402: (100!!)!!+1001/.1
403: (100!!)!!+s(((11!)!)*.1+0!)
404: ((11!)!)*.1001-(0!)
405: ((11!)!)*.1001
406: ((11!)!)*.1001+0!
407: (100!!)!!+100!-1
408: (100!!)!!+100!
409: (100!!)!!+100!+1
410: (100!!)!!+11010
411: (100!!)!!+100!+11
412: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!+0!))/.01
413: (100!!)!!-(0!)+(101!!)/.1
414: (100!!)!!+(101!!)/.1
415: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!))/.01-(0!)
416: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!))/.01
417: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!))/.01+0!
418: (((11!+0!)!!)/.1-(0!))/.1
419: ((11!+0!)!!)/.01-(0!)
420: ((11!+0!)!!)/.01
421: ((11!+0!)!!)/.01+0!
422: (((11!+0!)!!)/.1+0!)/.1
423: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(100!!+0!)
424: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)/.01
425: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)/.01+0!
426: (s((11!+0!)!+0!))*(11!)
427: (s((11!+0!)!+0!))*(11!)+0!
428: ((11!+0!)!!+0!+0!)/.01
429: (100!!)!!-(10+0!)+(11!)!!
430: (100!!)!!-(0!+0!)+(11!)!!
431: (100!!)!!-(0!)+(11!)!!
432: (100!!)!!+(11!)!!
433: (100!!)!!+(11!)!!+0!
434: (100!!)!!+(11!)!!+0!+0!
435: (100!!)!!+(11!)!!+10+0!
436: ((11!)^11+0!+0!)*(0!+0!)
437: (100!-(0!))*(s(((11!)!)*.1+0!))
438: (100!!)!!+(11!)!!+(10+0!)!
439: ((100!!)!!+0!)/.111-(0!)
440: ((100!!)!!+0!)/.111
441: 10101^(0!+0!)
442: 10101^10+0!
443: (100!!)!!-(0!)+(101!)*.1
444: (100!!)!!+(101!)*.1
445: (100!!)!!+(101!)*.1+0!
446: ((101!!)^10-(0!+0!))/.1
447: (100!!)!!-(0!)+.1^-(11!)
448: (100!!)!!+.1^-(11!)
449: ((11!)!)*.101-(0!)
450: ((11!)!)*.101
451: ((11!)!)*.101+0!
452: ((101!!)^(0!+0!)+0!)/.1
453: ((11!)!)*.101+0!+0!+0!
454: ((101!!)^10+0!+0!)/.1
455: (100!!)!!+s((11!+0!)!+0!)
456: (100!)*(s(((11!)!)*.1+0!))
457: (((0!+0!+0!)!)!)*.1+((11!)!!)/.1+0!
458: (((0!+0!+0!)!)!)*.1+((11!)!!+0!)/.1
459: ((11!+0!)!!+(11!)!!)*(0!+0!+0!)
460: ((11!)!!-(0!+0!))*1010
461: (((11!)!!)^(0!+0!)+0!)/101
462: (11!)!-(.1^-(100!!))-(0!+0!)
463: (11!)!-(.1^-(100!!))-(0!)
464: (11!)!-(.1^-(100!!))
465: ((11!)!)*.1+((0!+0!+0!)!+0!)!!
466: (11!)!-(.1^-(100!!))+0!+0!
467: ((100!!+0!)!!+0!)*.1-(11!)
468: (101!-10-(0!))/.01
469: ((11!)!!-(0!))*1010-(0!)
470: ((11!)!!-(0!))*1010
471: (1001!!-(0!))*.1-(0!)
472: ((100!!+0!)!!-(0!))*.1
473: ((100!!+0!)!!+0!)*.1
474: (1001!!+0!)*.1+0!
475: (101!-(0!))/.01-(0!)
476: (101!-(0!))/.01
477: (101!-(0!))/.01+0!
478: ((101!)/.1-(0!))/.1
479: ((11!)!)/1.1-(0!)
480: ((11!)!)/1.1
481: ((11!)!)/1.1+0!
482: ((101!)/.1+0!)/.1
483: (101!+0!)/.01-(0!)
484: (101!+0!)/.01
485: (101!+0!)/.01+0!
486: ((0!+0!+0!)^101)/.1
487: (100!!)!!-10+(11!+0!)!!
488: (101!+0!+0!)/.01
489: (100!!)!!+(11!+0!)!!
490: (100!!)!!+0!+(11!+0!)!!
491: (100!!)!!+111!!+0!+0!
492: ((11!)!)*.11-(((0!+0!+0!)!)!!)
493: ((11!)!-(0!))/.1-((100!!+0!)!!)
494: (11!)!-(0!)-((101!!)^(0!+0!))
495: (((0!+0!+0!)!)!)*.1011
496: (101!+100)/.01
497: (s((11!+0!)!+0!))*(11!+0!)
498: ((11!)!)*.101+((0!+0!+0!)!)!!
499 was not found
500: (1010^11)/(0!+0!)
501 was not found
502: (100!!)!!+101!-10
503: (100!!)!!+101!-(0!)
504: (100!!)!!+101!
505: (100!!)!!+101!+0!
506: .1^-(100!!+0!)-(11!)
507: .1^-(100!!+0!)-101
508: (.1^-(100!!)-(0!+0!))/.1
509: (.1^-(100!!)-(0!))/.1-(0!)
510: (.1^-(100!!)-(0!))/.1
511: .1^-(100!!+0!)-(0!)
512: .1^-(100!!+0!)
513: .1^-(100!!+0!)+0!
514: (.1^-(100!!)+0!)/.1
515: (.1^-(100!!)+0!)/.1+0!
516: (.1^-(100!!)+0!+0!)/.1
517: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(s(101!+0!))
518: .1^-(100!!+0!)+11!
519: .1^-(100!!+0!)+11!+0!
520: (.1^-(11!)+0!)/.001
521: (.1^-(11!)+0!)/.001+0!
522: ((11!)!-(((0!+0!)^(0!+0!))!))*.11
523: (100!-1)^(0!+0!)-(11!)
524: ((11!+0!)!!)*101-(0!)
525: ((11!+0!)!!)*101
526: ((11!+0!)!!)*101+0!
527: (11!)!-(0!)-(((100!!)!!)*.1)
528: ((11!)!!)*(s(101!+0!))
529: (100!-1)^(0!+0!)
530: (100!-1)^10+0!
531: (100!-1)^(.1^-1)+0!+0!
532: (100!-1)^(0!+0!)+11
533: ((11!)!)*.11-(0!)-((0!+0!+0!)!)
534: ((11!)!)*.11-((0!+0!+0!)!)
535: (100!-1)^(0!+0!)+11!
536: .001^-11+100!
537: ((11!)!)*.11-(0!+0!+0!)
538: ((11!)!)*.11-(0!+0!)
539: ((11!)!)*.11-(0!)
540: ((11!)!)*.11
541: ((11!)!)*.11+0!
542: ((11!)!)*.11+0!+0!
543: ((11!)!)*.11+0!+0!+0!
544: ((100!!)!!+100!)/.11
545: ((11!)!)*.11-(0!)+(0!+0!+0!)!
546: ((11!)!)*.11+(0!+0!+0!)!
547: ((11!)!)*.11+0!+(0!+0!+0!)!
548: ((11!)!)*.11+((0!+0!)^(0!+0!))!!
549 was not found
550: ((11!)!!+0!+0!)*(s(101!+0!))
551: ((11!)!+(100!!)!!)*.1-(0!)
552: ((11!)!+(100!!)!!)*.1
553: ((11!)!+(100!!)!!)*.1+0!
554: ((11!)!+(100!!)!!)*.1+0!+0!
555: ((11!)^(0!+0!)+0!)*(101!!)
556: ((100!!)!!-(0!)-((11!+0!)!!))/.1
557: ((100!!)!!-((11!+0!)!!))/.1-(0!)
558: ((100!!)!!-((11!+0!)!!))/.1
559: .1^-(100!!+0!)+(11!)!!-(0!)
560: ((11!+0!)!)/(100!!+0!)
561: 1001!!-((100!!)!!)
562: 1001!!+1-((100!!)!!)
563: (100!!)!!-(0!)+((11!)!)*.01
564: (((11!)!!-(0!))/.1)*((0!+0!+0!)!)
565: (100!!)!!+0!+((11!)!)*.01
566: (((11!)!!-(0!))*(11!)+0!)*(0!+0!)
567: (.1^-(11!)-(0!))*(100!!+0!)
568: (s((11!+0!)!+0!))/.001
569: (100!)^10-(11!+0!)
570: (100!)^(0!+0!)-(11!)
571: (100!)^10-101
572: (100!)^(.1^-1)-100
573: ((100!!)!!-(0!+0!))*1.1
574: (100!)^(.1^-1)-(0!+0!)
575: (100!)^10-(0!)
576: (100!)^(0!+0!)
577: (100!)^10+0!
578: (100!)^(.1^-1)+0!+0!
579: ((100!!)!!+0!+0!)*1.1
580: (100!)^(.1^-1)+100
581: (100!)^10+101
582: (100!)^(0!+0!)+11!
583: (100!)^10+11!+0!
584: (100!)^(.1^-1)+100!!
585: (((0!+0!+0!)!)!)*.1101
586: (100!!+0!)!!-(((11!)!)*.1)+0!
587: ((11!)!!+0!)*1100-(0!)
588: (((11!)!!+0!)/.1)*((0!+0!+0!)!)
589: ((11!)!!+0!)*1100+0!
590: (1001!!-(0!))*.101
591: (100!)^10+101!!
592: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!-(.1^-(11!+0!))
593: (11!)!+0!-((0!+0!)^(11!+0!))
594: (100!!)!!+((11!+0!)!!)/.1
595: (101!-(0!))*101
596: (101!-(0!))*101+0!
597: (11!)!-(101!+0!)-(0!+0!)
598: (11!)!-(101!+0!)-(0!)
599: (11!)!-(101!+0!)
600: (11!)!-(101!)
601: (11!)!-(101!-(0!))
602: (11!)!-(101!)+0!+0!
603: (11!)!-(101!)+0!+0!+0!
604: (101!+0!)*101-(0!)
605: (101!+0!)*101
606: (101!+0!)*101+0!
607 was not found
608: (.1^-(100!!)+(11!)!!)*(0!+0!)
609: (100!!)!!+(101!!)^10
610: (101!+0!+0!)*101
611: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(1100+0!)
612: ((100!!)!!+100!)*1.1
613: (11!)!-(0!+0!)-((11!+0!)!!)
614: (11!)!-(0!)-((11!+0!)!!)
615: (11!)!-((11!+0!)!!)
616: (11!)!+0!-((11!+0!)!!)
617: (11!)!+0!+0!-((11!+0!)!!)
618: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!+0!))*(11!)
619: (100!+1)^(0!+0!)-(11!)
620: (11!)!-(1010^(0!+0!))
621: (11!)!-((11!+0!)!!)+(0!+0!+0!)!
622: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!-(((11!)!!+0!)/.1)
623: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!-(((11!)!!)/.1+0!)
624: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!-(((11!)!!)/.1)
625: (100!+1)^(0!+0!)
626: 101^100+0!
627: 101^100+10
628: ((11!+0!)!!)*(11!)-(0!+0!)
629: ((11!+0!)!!)*(11!)-(0!)
630: ((11!+0!)!!)*(11!)
631: ((11!+0!)!!)*(11!)+0!
632: ((11!+0!)!!)*(11!)+0!+0!
633: ((111!!)/.1+0!)*(0!+0!+0!)
634: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)*(11!)-(0!+0!)
635: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)*(11!)-(0!)
636: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)*(11!)
637: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)*(11!)+0!
638: (1010!!)/(11!)-(0!+0!)
639: (1010!!)/(11!)-(0!)
640: (1010!!)/(11!)
641: (1010!!)/(11!)+0!
642: ((11!+0!)!!+0!+0!)*(11!)
643: ((11!+0!)!!+0!+0!)*(11!)+0!
644: ((11!)!!-(0!+0!))*(101!!-(0!))
645: ((11!)^11-(0!))*(0!+0!+0!)
646: ((11!)^100)*.1-(0!+0!)
647: ((11!)^100)*.1-(0!)
648: ((11!)^100)*.1
649: (11!)!-(s((11!+0!)!+0!))
650: (11!)!+0!-(s((11!+0!)!+0!))
651: ((11!)^11+0!)*(0!+0!+0!)
652 was not found
653 was not found
654: (11!)!-(0!+0!)-((0!+0!)^(11!))
655: (11!)!-(0!)-(.1^-((0!+0!+0!)!))
656: (11!)!-(.1^-((0!+0!+0!)!))
657: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!-(.1^-(11!)-(0!))
658: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(101!!-(0!))
659: (11!)!-(0!)-((101!)/(0!+0!))
660: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!-((101!)*.1)
661: (11!)!+0!-((101!)/(0!+0!))
662: ((100!!)!!)/.1-((11!+0!)!!)-(0!)
663: ((100!!)!!)/.1-((11!+0!)!!)
664: ((100!!)!!)/.1-((11!+0!)!!)+0!
665: (((11!)!!)/.1-(0!))*(100!!-(0!))
666: (11!)!-((11!)!!)-((0!+0!+0!)!)
667: (11!)!-((11!)!!)+0!-((0!+0!+0!)!)
668: (11!)!-((11!)!!)-((0!+0!)^(0!+0!))
669: (11!)!-((11!)!!)-(0!+0!+0!)
670: (11!)!-((11!)!!)-(0!+0!)
671: (11!)!-((11!)!!)-(0!)
672: (11!)!-((11!)!!)
673: (11!)!-((11!)!!)+0!
674: (11!)!-((11!)!!)+0!+0!
675: ((101!!)^(0!+0!))*11
676: 11010^(0!+0!)
677: 11010^10+0!
678: (11!)!-((11!)!!)+(0!+0!+0!)!
679: (((11!)!!)/.1+0!)*(100!!-(0!))
680: (11!)!-101000
681: (0!+0!+0!)^(11!)-((11!)!!)
682: (11!)!-(0!+0!)-((11!)^(0!+0!))
683: (11!)!-(0!)-((11!)^(0!+0!))
684: (11!)!-((11!)^(0!+0!))
685: (11!)!+0!-((11!)^(0!+0!))
686: ((11!+0!)^(0!+0!+0!))/.1
687: (11!)!-100001
688: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!-(.1^-101)
689: 1001!!-(.1^-(100!!))
690: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!-((101!!)/.1)
691: (11!)!+0!-((101!!)*(0!+0!))
692: (11!)!-(100!+100)
693: (11!)!-(11^(0!+0!+0!))
694: (11!)!-(100!+0!)-(0!)
695: (11!)!-(100!+0!)
696: (11!)!-(100!)
697: (11!)!-(100!-(0!))
698: (11!)!-(100!)+0!+0!
699: (11!)!-(10100+0!)
700: (11!)!-10100
701: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!-(s(((11!)!)*.1+0!))
702: (11!)!-10010
703: (11!)!-(0!)-(.01^-(0!+0!))
704: (11!)!-(.01^-(0!+0!))
705: (11!)!-(101!!)
706: (11!)!-(101!!-(0!))
707: (11!)!-(0!)-(((0!+0!+0!)!)/.1)
708: (11!)!-(((0!+0!+0!)!)/.1)
709: (11!)!-(s(101!+0!))
710: (11!)!-1010
711: (11!)!-(100!!+0!)
712: (11!)!-(100!!)
713: (11!)!-(11!+0!)
714: (11!)!-(11!)
715: (11!)!-101
716: (11!)!-100
717: (11!)!-11
718: (11!)!-(0!+0!)
719: (11!)!-(0!)
720: (11!)!
721: (11!)!+0!
722: (11!)!+0!+0!
723: (11!)!+11
724: (11!)!+100
725: (11!)!+101
726: (11!)!+11!
727: (11!)!+11!+0!
728: (11!)!+100!!
729: 11^(11!)
730: 11^(11!)+0!
731: 11^(11!)+0!+0!
732: (11!)!+((0!+0!+0!)!)/.1
733: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!+1101
734: (11!)!+101!!-(0!)
735: (11!)!+101!!
736: (11!)!+.01^-(0!+0!)
737: (11!)!+0!+.01^-(0!+0!)
738: (11!)!+10010
739: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!+s(((11!)!)*.1+0!)
740: (11!)!+10100
741: (11!)!+10100+0!
742: (11!)!-(0!+0!)+100!
743: (11!)!+100!-(0!)
744: (11!)!+100!
745: (11!)!+100!+0!
746: (11!)!+100!+0!+0!
747: (11!)!+11^(0!+0!+0!)
748: (11!)!+100!+100
749: (11!)!-(0!)+(101!!)*(0!+0!)
750: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!+(101!!)/.1
751: (11!)!-(0!)+(100!!)/.01
752: ((11!)!!-(0!))/.0001
753: ((100!!)!!)/.1-(101!!)
754: ((100!!)!!-(11!+0!))/.1
755: (11!)!-(0!)+(11!)^(0!+0!)
756: ((100!!)!!-(11!))/.1
757: (11!)!+0!+(11!)^(0!+0!)
758: ((100!!)!!-101)/.1
759: ((100!!)!!)/.1-1001
760: ((100!!)!!-100)/.1
761: ((100!!)!!)/.1-(11!+0!)
762: ((100!!)!!-11)/.1
763: ((100!!)!!-10)/.1-(0!)
764: ((100!!)!!-(0!+0!))/.1
765: ((100!!)!!-(0!))/.1-(0!)
766: ((100!!)!!-(0!))/.1
767: ((100!!)!!)/.1-(0!)
768: ((100!!)!!)/.1
769: ((100!!)!!)/.1+0!
770: ((100!!)!!+0!)/.1
771: ((100!!)!!+0!)/.1+0!
772: ((100!!)!!+0!+0!)/.1
773: ((100!!)!!+10)/.1+0!
774: ((100!!)!!+11)/.1
775: ((100!!)!!)/.1+11!+0!
776: ((100!!)!!+100)/.1
777: (0!+0!+0!)^(11!)+(11!)!!
778: ((100!!)!!+101)/.1
779: ((100!!)!!+11!)/.1-(0!)
780: ((100!!)!!+11!)/.1
781: ((100!!)!!+11!)/.1+0!
782: ((100!!)!!+11!+0!)/.1
783: (11!)!-(0!)+.1^-((0!+0!+0!)!)
784: (11!)!+.1^-((0!+0!+0!)!)
785: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!+.1^-(11!)+0!
786: ((100!!)!!+1001)/.1
787 was not found
788: ((100!!)!!+1010)/.1
789: (11!)!-(0!+0!)+s((11!+0!)!+0!)
790: (11!)!-(0!)+s((11!+0!)!+0!)
791: (11!)!+s((11!+0!)!+0!)
792: ((100!!)!!)/.1+100!
793: ((100!!)!!)/.1+100!+1
794: ((100!!)!!+1)/.1+100!
795 was not found
796: ((100!!)!!+101!!-(0!))/.1
797: ((100!!)!!+101!!)/.1-(0!)
798: ((100!!)!!+101!!)/.1
799: ((11!)!!-(0!))*10001
800: (10100^10)/.1
801: (11!)!+(10+0!)^100
802 was not found
803 was not found
804: ((100!!)!!)/.1+(11!)^(0!+0!)
805 was not found
806 was not found
807 was not found
808: ((11!)!)*1.001-(0!+0!)
809: ((11!)!)*1.001-(0!)
810: ((11!)!)*1.001
811: ((11!)!)*1.001+0!
812: (11!)!+(100!-(0!))/.01
813: (11!)!-(0!)+((11!)!!-(0!))*(0!+0!)
814: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!+((11!)!!-(0!))/.1
815: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!+((11!)!!)/.1-(0!)
816: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!+((11!)!!)/.1
817: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!+((11!)!!)/.1+0!
818: ((0!+0!+0!)!)!+((11!)!!+0!)/.1
819: (11!)!+0!+((11!)!!+0!)*(0!+0!)
820: (11!)!+1010^(0!+0!)
821 was not found
822: (11!)!-(0!+0!)-(0!)+(11!+0!)!!
823: (11!)!-(0!+0!)+(11!+0!)!!
824: (11!)!-(0!)+(11!+0!)!!
825: (11!)!+(11!+0!)!!
826: (11!)!+0!+(11!+0!)!!
827: (11!)!+0!+0!+(11!+0!)!!
828: ((11!)^10)*(100!-(0!))
829 was not found
830: (((11!+0!)!!-(0!))/.01-(0!))/.1
831: (111!!-(0!))*(100!!)-(0!)
832: ((11!+0!)!!-(0!))/.001
833: (101!-(0!))*(11!+0!)
834: (101!-(0!))*(11!+0!)+0!
835: (((11!+0!)!!)/.1-(0!))/.01-(0!)
836: (((11!+0!)!!)/.1-(0!))/.01
837: (11!)!-(0!+0!)+101!-(0!)
838: ((100!!)!)/((11!)!!)-(0!+0!)
839: ((100!!)!)/((11!)!!)-(0!)
840: ((100!!)!)/((11!)!!)
841: ((100!!)!)/((11!)!!)+0!
842: ((100!!)!)/((11!)!!)+0!+0!
843: (11!)!+101!+0!+0!+0!
844: (((11!+0!)!!)/.1+0!)/.01
845: (11!)!+101^(0!+0!+0!)
846: ((11!)!!-(0!))*10010
847: (101!+0!)*(11!+0!)
848: ((11!+0!)!!+0!)/.001
849: (100!!+0!)!!-(((11!)!!)/.1)
850: (100!!+0!)!!-(((11!)!!)/.1)+0!
851: (100!!+0!)!!-(((11!)!!-(0!))/.1)
852: ((s(111!+0!))/.1)*((0!+0!+0!)!)
853 was not found
854: (101!+0!+0!)*(11!+0!)
855: (((11!)!!)/.1-(0!))*(100!!+0!)
856: (111!!+0!+0!)/.001
857 was not found
858: (((11!)!!)*11-(0!))*((0!+0!+0!)!)
859 was not found
860: ((11!)^(10+0!)-(0!))/.01
861: (((11!)!!)*(11!)-(0!))*(0!+0!+0!)
862: ((100!!)!!-(0!)+(11!)!!)/.1
863: ((100!!)!!+(11!)!!)/.1-(0!)
864: ((100!!)!!+(11!)!!)/.1
865: ((100!!)!!+(11!)!!)/.1+0!
866: ((100!!)!!+(11!)!!+0!)/.1
867: (((11!)!!)*(11!)+0!)*(0!+0!+0!)
868: ((11!)^(10+0!)+0!)/.01
869 was not found
870: (((11!)!!)*11+0!)*((0!+0!+0!)!)
871: ((100!!)!!-(0!))/.1+(11!+0!)!!
872: ((100!!)!!)/.1-(0!)+(11!+0!)!!
873: ((100!!)!!)/.1+(11!+0!)!!
874: (100!!+0!)!!-(s(111!+0!))
875: ((100!!)!!+0!)/.1+(11!+0!)!!
876: ((11!+0!)!)*.01-((100!!)!!)
877 was not found
878 was not found
879 was not found
880: ((100!!)!!+0!)/.0111
881: (100!!+0!)!!-(.1^-(11!))
882: ((11!)!!+0!)*10010
883 was not found
884 was not found
885: (100!!+0!)!!-((101!)*.1)
886: ((100!!)!!-(0!))/.1+101!
887: ((100!!)!!)/.1+101!-(0!)
888: ((100!!)!!)/.1+101!
889: ((100!!)!!)/.1+101!+0!
890: ((100!!)!!+0!)/.1+101!
891 was not found
892 was not found
893: ((11!)!!-(0!))*(s(((11!)!)/(0!+0!)+0!))
894: ((11!)!)*1.01-((0!+0!+0!)!)
895: 1001!!-(0!)-((11!)!!)-(0!)
896: (100!!+0!)!!-((11!)!!+0!)
897: (100!!+0!)!!-((11!)!!)
898: (100!!+0!)!!-((11!)!!-(0!))
899: ((11!)!)*1.01-(0!)
900: ((11!)!)*1.01
```

The solver can be found here: https://github.com/isaacg1/eight-bits/

Caveats:

- The solver does not consider intermediate steps with value above 65535.
- The solver does not consider intermediate steps with negative value, except in special cases such as `.1^-x`.
- The solver does not consider intermediate steps with fractional value. Literals with fractional value are used, but intermediate steps with fractional value are not.

I believe that my solver finds all possible solutions that do not go through one of the above three cases.

Comment: Excellent work! Though I think the tiebreaker should also include something for "number of characters used." $0!$ instead of just $1$ seems kinda silly. :)  Also... man, I think I have to learn Rust at some point.

Comment: Awesome. :-). Because it cant find all cases do you want to put 500 - 1000 up as-well so we can all work together on the gaps ???

Comment: What am I missing? I get the 385*5/6 to be irrational. $320 \frac{5}{6}$ not 462.

Comment: Weather Vane: 385/(5/6) does it, beautifully!

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos so it's just a typo in the post. The `462 = ((100!!)!!+0!)*(0!-1/11!)` should be `((100!!)!!+0!)/(0!-1/11!)` - edited.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the edit

Comment: @Mike Updated, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for extending the list.

Comment: Is interpretation of the brackets as binomial coefficient allowed?


If yes, we can do $462 = \binom{11}{5}$ with f.e.
$462 = \binom{1100-0!}{101}$

Comment: Thomasi: Not for now!

Comment: I extended my generator to use fractional intermediate values and have two new results
 
$ 549 = ((0! + 0! + 0!)! + (11!)! \times .1) \times (.1 + 0!) $ and 

$ 795 = ((\frac{0! + 0!}{.1})!! - .1) \times ((11! + 0!)!! + 0!) $

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos 499 = 101^11/((.(0!))*(.(0!)))-0!, where each .(0!) becomes .1 by concatenation, if .x is allowed to be treated as -x currently is. Actual subtraction requires 0-x, costing an extra 0; this means -x either uses negation (aka unary minus or sign reversal) -- which is not listed in the question currently -- or concatenation). Still working on getting the question clarified. A mathematician friend told me that this type of problem is "really hard to make precise" -- and I don't disagree....

Comment: Rick Shepard: Very nice trick, but I mean "simple concatenation", which most seem to understand what it is about. For the record, yours is an alternative, if everything else fails.

Answer (score 11):

Continuing from @Dante . . .

> $ 26 = 100! + 10 + 0 + 1 - 1 $
>  $ 27 = 11^{11} + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 $
>  $ 28 = 100! + 100 + 1 - 1 $
>  $ 29 = 100! + 10 + 11 + 0 $
>  $ 30 = 10^{101} - 10 + 0 $
>  $ 31 = 10^{101} - 1 + 0 + 0 $
>  $ 32 = 10^{(110 - 1)} + 0 + 0 $
>  $ 33 = 10^{101} + 1 + 0 + 0 $
>  $ 34 = 10^{101} + 10 + 0 $
>  $ 35 = 100! + 1011 + 0 $
>  $ 36 = 10^{101} + 100 $
>  $ 37 = 100! + 1101 + 0 $
>  $ 38 = 110^{10} + 10 + 0 $
>  $ 39 = 100111 + 0 + 0 $
>  $ 40 = 101000 + 1 - 1 $
>  $ 41 = 101001^{1} + 0 $
>  $ 42 = 101010^{1} + 0 $
>  $ 43 = 101011 + 0 + 0 $
>  $ 44 = 101100^{1} + 0 $
>  $ 45 = 101101 + 0 $
>  $ 46 = 101110 + 0 $
>  $ 47 = 110000 - 1^{1} $
>  $ 48 = 110000 + 1 - 1 $
>  $ 49 = 110000 + 1^{1} $
>  $ 50 = 110000 + 1 + 1 $
>  $ 51 = 110000 + 11 $
>  $ 52 = (100! + 10) \times 10^{1} $
>  $ 53 = ((100! + 10) \times 10) + 1 $
>  $ 54 = 11^{11} \times (0^{0} + 0^{0}) $
>  $ 55 = 111000 - 1 + 0 $
>  $ 56 = 111000^{1} + 0 $
>  $ 57 = 111000 + 1 + 0 $
>  $ 58 = 111000 + 10 $
>  $ 59 = \frac{101!}{10} - 1 + 0 + 0 $
>  $ 60 = 111100 + 0 + 0 $
>  $ 61 = \frac{101!}{10} + 1 + 0 + 0  $
>  $ 62 = 100^{11} - 10 + 0 $
>  $ 63 = 100^{11} - 1 + 0 + 0 $
>  $ 64 = 100^{11} + 0^{1} + 0 $
>  $ 65 = 100^{11} + 1 + 0 $
>  $ 66 = 100^{11} + 10 $
>  $ 67 = ? $

Any more?

Comment: You've overlooked the simple $67=1000011/1$ or $67=1000011^1$.

Comment: Indeed I don't know how I missed that (and several other variants) e.g. $1000011 \times 1$. I'll let someone else pick up the baton.

Comment: Only 3 $0$s were used in 66.

Comment: @PlaceReporter99 somehow several others only have 3 zeros but as noted elsewhere you can trivially add 0 or multiply by 1 to use up the spare digits.

Answer (score 11):

Continuing from Dante and Weather Vane:

(EDIT: Extended it further, but left some gaps. Either other users will fill them, or I will tomorrow, or one of them is the answer. Outstanding numbers are: <s>158</s>, <s>159</s>, <s>164</s>, <s>173</s>, <s>187</s>, <s>188</s>, <s>190</s>, <s>199</s>)

> Note that 'precisely 4 1s and 4 0s' is equivalent to 'up to 4 1s and 4 0s', since we can trivially add 0 or multiply by 1 use up additional digits. These trivial digits have been omitted for readability.

> $ 67 = 1000011 $
>  $ 68 = 1000011 + 1 $
>  $ 69 = 1000101 $
>  $ 70 = 1000110 $
>  $ 71 = 1000111 $
>  $ 72 = 1001001 - 1 $
>  $ 73 = 1001001 $
>  $ 74 = 1001010 $
>  $ 75 = 1001011 $
>  $ 76 = 1001100 $
>  $ 77 = 1001101 $
>  $ 78 = 1001110 $
>  $ 79 = 11^{100} - 10$
>  $ 80 = 1010001 - 1 $
>  $ 81 = 1010001 $
>  $ 82 = 1010010 $
>  $ 83 = 1010011 $
>  $ 84 = 1010100 $
>  $ 85 = 1010101 $
>  $ 86 = 1010110 $
>  $ 87 = 1010110 + 0! $
>  $ 88 = 1011000 $
>  $ 89 = 1011001 $
>  $ 90 = 1011010 $
>  $ 91 = 1011010 + 0! $
>  $ 92 = 1011100 $
>  $ 93 = 1011100 + 0! $
>  $ 94 = (100 + 0!)! - 11010 $
>  $ 95 = (100 + 0!)! - 11001 $
>  $ 96 = 101! - 11000 $
>  $ 97 = 1100001 $
>  $ 98 = 1100010 $
>  $ 99 = 1100011 $
>  $ 100 = 1100100 $
>  $ 101 = 1100101 $
>  $ 102 = 1100110 $
>  $ 103 = 1100110 + 0! $
>  $ 104 = 1101000 $
>  $ 105 = 1101001 $
>  $ 106 = 1101010 $
>  $ 107 = 1101010 + 0! $
>  $ 108 = 1101100 $
>  $ 109 = 1101100 + 0! $
>  $ 110 = 101! - 1010 $
>  $ 111 = 1110000 - 1 $
>  $ 112 = 1110000 $
>  $ 113 = 1110001 $
>  $ 114 = 1110010 $
>  $ 115 = 1110010 + 0! $
>  $ 116 = 1110100 $
>  $ 117 = 1110100 + 0! $
>  $ 118 = 101! - 10 $
>  $ 119 = 101! - 1 $
>  $ 120 = 101! $
>  $ 121 = 101! + 1 $
>  $ 122 = 101! + 10 $
>  $ 123 = 101! + 11 $
>  $ 124 = 101! + 100 $
>  $ 125 = 101! + 101 $
>  $ 126 = 101! + 110 $
>  $ 127 = 101! + 110 + 0! $
>  $ 128 = 10^{111} $
>  $ 129 = 10^{111} + 0! $
>  $ 130 = 10^{111} + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 131 = 10^{111} + 0! + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 132 = 101! + 1100 $
>  $ 133 = 101! + 1100 + 0! $
>  $ 134 = (100 + 0!)! + 1110 $
>  $ 135 = 10000111\ \ \text{(Jaap Scherphuis)} $
>  $ 136 = 101! + 100^{10} $
>  $ 137 = 101! + 10001 $
>  $ 138 = 101! + 10010 $
>  $ 139 = 10001011 $
>  $ 140 = 101! + 10100 $
>  $ 141 = 10001101 $
>  $ 142 = 10001110 $
>  $ 143 = \frac{(11!)!}{101} - 0!  $
>  $ 144 = \frac{(11!)!}{101} $
>  $ 145 = \frac{(11!)!}{101} + 0! $
>  $ 146 = \frac{(11!)!}{101} + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 147 = \frac{(11!)!}{101} + 0! + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 148 = (11!^{10} + 0!) \times 100\ \ \text{(loopy walt)} $
>  $ 149 = 10010101 (\text{ Bass}) $
>  $ 150 = 10010110 (\text{ Bass}) $
>  $ 151 = (100! + 0!) \times 110 + 1 $
>  $ 152 = 101! + (0! + 0!)^{101} $
>  $ 153 = 10011001 $
>  $ 154 = (100! - 0! - 0!) \times 111 $
>  $ 155 = 101! + (11!)^{0! + 0!} - 0! $
>  $ 156 = \frac{(11!)!}{100} - 100! $
>  $ 157 = 101! + (11!)^{0! + 0!} + 0! $
>  $ 158 = \frac{(11!)!}{100.1}-(0!+0!)\ \ \text{(MountainEucalyptus)} $
>  $ 159 = \frac{(11!)!}{100.1}-(0!)\ \ \text{(MountainEucalyptus)} $
>  $ 160 = 101 \times (0! + 0!)^{101} $
>  $ 161 = (100! - 0!) \times 111 $
>  $ 162 = (100! - 0!) \times 111 + 0! $
>  $ 163 = 10100011 $
>  $ 164 = 10 \times (11^{100} + 0!)\ \ \text{(loopy walt)} $
>  $ 165 = 101! \times (0! + 0.011) $
>  $ 166 = 100! \times 111 - 0! - 0! $
>  $ 167 = 100! \times 111 - 0! $
>  $ 168 = 100! \times 111 $
>  $ 169 = 100! \times 111 + 0! $
>  $ 170 = 100! \times 111 + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 171 = 1101^{10} + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 172 = 10101100 $
>  $ 173 = (11!)! \times .01 - 1 - (0!+0!+0!)!\ \ \text{(Retudin)} $
>  $ 174 = (100! + 0!) \times 111 - 0! $
>  $ 175 = (100! + 0!) \times 111 $
>  $ 176 = (100! + 0!) \times 111 + 0! $
>  $ 177 = \frac{(11!)!}{100} - 10 - 0! $
>  $ 178 = \frac{(11!)!}{100} - 10 $
>  $ 179 = \frac{(11!)!}{100} - 0! $
>  $ 180 = \frac{(11!)!}{100} $
>  $ 181 = \frac{(11!)!}{100} + 0! $
>  $ 182 = \frac{(11!)!}{100} + 10 $
>  $ 183 = \frac{(11!)!}{100} + 10 + 0! $
>  $ 184 = \frac{(11!)!}{100} + 100 $
>  $ 185 = 101! + (0! + 0!)^{11!} + 0! $
>  $ 186 = \frac{(11!)!}{100} + (10 + 0!)! $
>  $ 187 = (((1 + 1 + 1)!)!! - 0!) \times 100 - 0!\ \ \text{(Weather Vane)}  $
>  $ 188 = ((0! + 0!)^{11!} - 0!) \times 11 - 0!\ \ \text{(loopy walt)} $
>  $ 189 = (10^{11!} - 0!) \times (10 + 0!) $
>  $ 190 = (0! + 0!)^{11!} \times 11 - 0! - 0!\ \ \text{(loopy walt)} $
>  $ 191 = 10^{11!} \times (10 + 0!) - 0! $
>  $ 192 = 10^{11!} \times (10 + 0!) $
>  $ 193 = 10^{11!} \times (10 + 0!) + 0! $
>  $ 194 = 1110^{10} - 0! - 0! $
>  $ 195 = (10^{11!} + 0!) \times (10 + 0!) $
>  $ 196 = 1110^{10} $
>  $ 197 = 11000101 $
>  $ 198 = 11000110 $
>  $ 199 = (100! + 0!)/(.1^{11}) - 0!\ \ \text{(isaacg)} $
>  $ 200 = (100! + 0!) \times (111 + 0!) $
>  $ 201 = 11001001 $
>  $ 202 = 11001010 $

Comment: Like Weather Vane, you stopped just before an easy one: $135=10000111$. I got stuck at 107 cause I didn't think of the 0! trick. Very nice!

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Great spot! Have updated.

Comment: 148 = (11!^10+0!)x100

Comment: @loopywalt good one. Can you carry on?

Comment: 149=10010101, 150=10010110 :-)

Comment: Typo at 162? Did you mean `10 x 11^100` ?

Comment: 190 = (0!+0!)^11! x 11 - 0!-0!

Comment: 164 = 10 x (11^100 + 0!)

Comment: 158=(11^100-0!-0!)/.1

Comment: 188 = ((0!+0!)^11! - 0!) x 11 - 0!

Comment: @JaapScherphuis you beat me to 188 and 190 by a short stroke, but I added 187.

Comment: @WeatherVane You mean loopy walt. All I did in my edit was a little formatting.

Comment: @WeatherVane Although factorial are allowed, I'm not so sure double factorials are. It hasn't been needed so far, and earlier expressions with $!!$ were actually repeated factorials (i.e. $11_2!!=3!!=(3!)!=6!=720$, whereas you used $(11_2!)!!=(3!)!!=6!!=6\cdot4\cdot2=48$).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis (I thought) many of the solutions listed had a double factorial!!

Comment: So either mine needs to be deleted, or the others need parentheses applying.

Comment: 199 = (100! + 0!)/(.1^11) - 0!. This uses the fractional point with no leading digit, and it's unclear whether that's allowed, so I've asked for clarification

Comment: 173 = 11!! x .01 - 1 - (0!+0!+0!)!

Comment: Better write the above as (11!)! x 0.01 -  (0!+0!+0!)!

Comment: Note that we can avoid the double factorial in 187 by reusing Retudin's solution: (11!)!*.01 + 1 + (0! + 0! + 0!)!. But there's no need, as both are allowed.

Answer (score 10):

I *tentatively* claimed that 265 is the answer, since I thought I did a pretty good go at trying to solve it, and didn't manage it. Commenters have managed to fill all the gaps in this answer, from 263 to 307

Continuing from Dante, Weather Vane, BlueHairedMeerkat, and Mike's efforts. As with their answers, please comment or edit in any gaps you solve.

Gaps at: <s>265-267, 275-279, 281, 283, 293, 295, 297, and 303 onward</s>

Like BlueHairedMeerkat's answer:

> Note that 'precisely 4 1s and 4 0s' is equivalent to 'up to 4 1s and 4 0s', since we can trivially add 0 or multiply by 1 use up additional digits. These trivial digits have been omitted for readability.

> $263 = 10^{100!!}+11!+0!$
> $264 = 10^{100!!}+(11+0!)!!$
> $265 = 101!/.1+100!+0!$
> $266 = (101!+0!)/.1+100!$
> $267 = (11!)!*.011-0!-0!-0!$
> $268 = (11!)!*.011-0!-0!$
> $269 = 101! \times 10.01-0!$
> $270 = 101! \times 10.01$
> $271 = 101! \times 10.01+0!$
> $272 = (101!!)^{0!+0!}+(11!)!!-0!$
> $273 = (101!!)^{0!+0!}+(11!)!!$
> $274 = (101!!)^{0!+0!}+(11!)!!+0!$
> $275 = (100!-0!)*11!/.1-0!$
> $276 = (100!-0!)*11!/.1$
> $277 = (100!-0!)*11!/.1+0!$
> $278 = (11!+0!)!!/.011-0!-0!?$
> $279 = (11!+0!)!!/.011-0!$
> $280 = (11!)!/(0!+0!+.1)-100!!$
> $281 = (11!+0!)!!/.011+0!$
> $282 = (11!)!/(0!+0!+.1)-(10+0!)!$
> $283 = ((11!)!!-0!)*11!+0!$
> $284 = (11!)!/(0!+0!+.1)-100$
> $285 = (11!)!/(10.1)-0!-0!-0!$
> $286 = (11!)!/(10.1)-0!-0!$
> $287 = (11!)!/(10.1)-0!$
> $288 = (11!)!/(10.1)$
> $289 = (11!)!/(10.1)+0!$
> $290 = (11!)!/(10.1)+0!+0!$
> $291 = (11!)!/(10.1)+0!+0!+0!$
> $292 = (11!)!/(0!+0!+.1)+100$
> $293 = ((11!)!!+0!)*11!-0!$
> $294 = (11!)!/(0!+0!+.1)+(10+0!)!$
> $295 = ((11!)!!+0!)*11!+0!$
> $296 = (11!)!/(0!+0!+.1)+100!!$
> $297 = ((11!)!!+0!)*11!+0!+0!+0!$
> $298 = 101! \times 10.1-0!-0!$
> $299 = 101! \times 10.1-0!$
> $300 = 101! \times 10.1$
> $301 = 101! \times 10.1+0!$
> $302 = 101! \times 10.1+0!+0!$
> $303 = ((0!+0!+0!)!!+10.1)*11!$
> $304 = (0!+1)^{100!!}+(11!)!!$
> $305 = (0!+1)^{100!!}+(11!)!!+0!$
> $306 = ((11!)!!+0!+0!+0!)*11!$
> $307 = ((11!)!!+0!+0!+0!)*11!+0!$

Comment: I can't comment on Mike's answer, and I feel that it is inappropriate to solve the gaps from that answer in a separate place. Can someone please look through my rejected edit on Mike's answer and either comment the solutions I offered or edit them in?

Comment: Mountain, maybe leave your proposed solutions for Mike's range in the comments on this answer? I can't see your rejected edit

Comment: 265 = 101!/.1 + 100! + 0!. 266 = (101! +0!)/.1 +100!

Comment: 267 = (11!)! x .011 - 0! - 0! - 0!

Comment: 276 = (100!-0!) x 11! / .1; 275,277 = 276 +/- 0!

Comment: 280 = (11!+0!)!! / .011; 278-282 = 280 +/- 0! [+/-0!]

Comment: 295 = (101! - 0! - 0!) x 10.1

Comment: 274-302 =((11!)!! [[+/- 0!] +/- 0!]) x 11! [[[+/- 0!] +/- 0!] +/- 0!]

Comment: 303 = ((0!+0!+0!)!! + 10.1) x 11!

Comment: $ 304 = (0! + 1) ^ {100!!} + (11!)!! $ and add 0! to give 305.

Comment: $ 306 = ((11!)!! + 0! + 0! + 0!) \times 11! $

Comment: I don't have 310 but I do have 311 thru 322 and many higher ones, for example an unbroken sequence from 352 thru 400.

Comment: one of which is $ 395 = (100!!)!! + \sqrt{((11! - 0!)! + 0!)} $ with a spare 1.

Comment: @WeatherVane Just having $384 = (100!!)!!$ is a huge tool. We can get $288$ using just three ones, as $.11 \cdot (100!!)!!$

Comment: @Eric Snyder (11!)! and (100!!)!! give most of the range I mentioned.

Comment: using double factorial with 7!!=105, we can get
     
$$308 = (((11)!+0!)!!-0!-0!)*11-0!$$
$$309 = (((11)!+0!)!!-0!-0!)*11+0$$
$$310 = (((11)!+0!)!!-0!-0!)*11+0!$$

Comment: With $310$ taken care of, taking WeatherVane at face value on 311-322, I have $324 = (10 \cdot 1001)^{10}$. Thought I could stretch to $323, 325$ but that one's tight.

Comment: @EricSnyder $ 324 = 10010 ^ {10} $ with a spare 1.

Answer (score 8):

26. 

First 25 numbers can be written as

1:10-10+10-01

2:(11-01-00)^(01)

3:10+01+10-10

4:(10^10)*(01^01)

5:0111-0010

6:0111-0001

7:(10^11)-01-00

8:(11^10)-0001

9:0110+0011

10:0101+0101

11:0101+0110

12:(10*10)*11+00

13:1110-0001

14:1101+0001

15:1010+0101

16:10*10*10*10

17:((10^10)^10)+01

18:1001+1001

19:1000+1011

20:1010+1010

21:1100+1001

22:1010+1100

23:00010111

24:1000*011*1

25:((11+10)^10)+00

Comment: How about 100!+10+0+1-1

Comment: Among others, I've just attempted to change the incorrect expression for 24 to 1000*011*1, and I'd also like to see the one for 16 changed to be 10*10*10*10, which already seemed to be there while I was creating my edit.  However, my pending edit shows the first without the asterisks. I don't understand why. Maybe the second is in someone else's pending edit. I don't know; I'm new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently asterisks cause italics to be used. I'll learn later how to suppress that if possible -- unless someone wants to say so here. I believe one of the original expressions had partial italics already, too. Apologies for the comments here.

Comment: @RickShepherd fixed. (use a backslash to escape asterisks, so they are not treated as italics markup)

Comment: @Rubio Thanks -- on both counts.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks everyone for your contributions.

203 = 111!!/.1-(0!+0!+0!)!-0! (isaacg)
204 = 11001100
205 = 111!!/.1-(0!+0!+0!)!+0! (isaacg)
206 = 111!!/.1-0!-0!-0!-0! (isaacg)
207 = 111!!*10-0!-0!-0!
208 = 111!!*10-0!-0!
209 = 11010001
210 = 110^11-(0!+0!+0!)!
211 = 111!!*10+0! (P.-S. Park)
212 = 11010100
213 = 110^11-0!-0!-0!
214 = 110^11-0!-0!+0
215 = 110^11-0!+0+0!
216 = 110^11+0+0+0
217 = 110^11+0!+0+0
218 = 110^11+0!+0!+0
219 = 110^11+0!+0!+0!
220 = 11!^11+0!+0!+0!+0!
221 = 11!^11+(0!+0!+0!)!-0!
222 = 110^11+(0!+0!+0!)!
223 = 1111^(0!+0!)-0!-0!
224 = 1111^(0!+0!)-(0!+0)
225 = 1111^(0!+0!)+0+0
226 = 1111^(0!+0!)+(0!+0)
227 = 1111^(0!+0!)+0!-0!
228 = (101!-(10+0!)!*10
229 = (101!-(10+0!)!/.1+0!
230 = (101!-100-0!)/.1
231 = (101!-100)/.1-0!
232 = (101!-100)*10
233 = 101! / .1-(0!+0!+0!)!-1 (P.-S. Park)
234 = 101!*10-(10+0!)!
235 = 101!/.1-100-0! (P.-S. Park)
236 = 101!*10-100
237 = 101!*10-0!-10
238 = 101!*10-10+0
239 = 101!*10-1+0+0
240 = 101!*10*(0+0+1)
241 = 101!*10+1+0+0
242 = 101!*10+10+0
243 = 101!*10+10+0!?
244 = 101!*10+100
245 = 11^101+0!+0!+0
246 = 101!*10+(10+0!)!
247 = (101!+100)/.1-0! (P.-S. Park)
248 = (101^11-0!)*(0!+0!)
249 = (101^11)*(0!+0!)-0!
250 = 10^1000-11!
251 = (101^11)*(0!+0!)+0!
252 = (101^11+0!)*(0!+0!)
253 = 10^1000-11
254 = 10^1000-1-1
255 = 10^1000-1^1
256 = 10^1000+1-1
257 = 10^1000+1^1
258 = 10^1000+1+1
259 = 10^1000+11
260 = 10^(100!!)+11+0!
261 = 10^(100!!)+101
262 = 10^1000+11!

Someone can continue from here. If you contributed an answer feel free to put your username next to it.

Comment: 211 = 111!! * 10 + 0! + 0 + 0

Comment: 203 = 111!!/.1 - (0! + 0! + 0!)! - 0!. The same idea works for 205 and 206.

Comment: 233 = 101! / .1 - (0! + 0! + 0!)! - 1
Where is my name?

Comment: 235 = 101!/.1-(0!+0!+0!)!+1

Comment: 247 = 101!/.1+(0!+0!+0!)!+1

Comment: 229 = (101!-(0!+0!+0!)!)/.1+1
@isaacg's idea works well.

Comment: 230 = (101!-(0!+0!+0!)!+1)/.1

Comment: The `/.1` is a nice save of a 0 that can be used in other places where it's currently `*10`. Get a few more answers.

Comment: My engine found some that are quite convoluted: $ 260 = (0! + 0! + .1) \times ((\sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)})!! - 0!) $

Answer (score 6):

Some more: 311 to 409 with gaps.
Edit by @Joel Rondeau just leaves 326 unsolved in this range.
Update: Contribution by @isaacg completes the range.

> $ 311 = (11!)! \times .1 - 0! - ((1 + 0! + 0!)!)!! $
>  $ 312 = (11!)! \times .1 - ((1 + 0! + 0!)!)!! $
>  $ 313 = (11!)! \times .1 + 0! - ((1 + 0! + 0!)!)!! $
>  $ 314 = (\sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)})!! \times 11 - 0! $
>  $ 315 = (\sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)})!! \times 11 $
>  $ 316 = (\sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)})!! \times 11 + 0! $
>  $ 317 = (\sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)})!! \times 11 + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 318 = ((\sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)})!! + 0!) \times 11 $
>  $ 319 = ((\sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)})!! + 0!) \times 11 + 0! $
>  $ 320 = (0! + 0!) ^ {11!} \times 101 $
>  $ 321 = ((\sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)})!! + 0! + 0!) \times 11 $
>  $ 322 = ((11!)!! - 0! - 0!) \times \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} $
>  $ 323 = 10010 ^ {10} - 1 $
>  $ 324 = 10010 ^ {10} $
>  $ 325 = 10010 ^ {10} + 1 $
>  $ 326 = (11! \times 11)^{(0!+0!)}+0!+0! $
>  $ 327 = ((11!)!! - 0!) \times (11! + 0!) - 0! - 0! $
>  $ 328 = ((11!)!! - 0!) \times \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} - 0! $
>  $ 329 = ((11!)!! - 0!) \times \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} $
>  $ 330 = ((11!)!! - 0!) \times \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} + 0! $
>  $ 331 = ((11!)!! - 0!) \times (11! + 0!) + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 332 = (100!!)!! - (11!)!! - 100 $
>  $ 333 = (100!!)!! - (11!)!! - 10 - 0! $
>  $ 334 = (100!!)!! - 0! - 0! - (11!)!! $
>  $ 335 = (11!)! - 0! - ((1 + 0! + 0! + 0!)!!)!! $
>  $ 336 = (11!)! - ((1 + 0! + 0! + 0!)!!)!! $
>  $ 337 = (11!)! + 0! - ((1 + 0! + 0! + 0!)!!)!! $
>  $ 338 = (100!!)!! + 0! + 0! - (11!)!! $
>  $ 339 = (11!)! - (100!!)!! + 1 + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 340 = (11! + 0!) ^ {11} - 0! - 0! - 0! $
>  $ 341 = \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} ^ {11} - 0! - 0! $
>  $ 342 = \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} ^ {11} - 0! $
>  $ 343 = \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} ^ {11} $
>  $ 344 = \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} ^ {11} + 0! $
>  $ 345 = (100! - 0!) \times (11! - 0!)!! $
>  $ 346 = (11! + 0!) ^ {11} + 0! + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 347 = ((11!)! - (1 + 0! + 0! + 0!)!) \times .1 - 0! $
>  $ 348 = ((11!)! - (1 + 0! + 0! + 0!)!) \times .1 $
>  $ 349 = ((11!)!! + 0! + 0!) \times \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} - 0! $
>  $ 350 = ((11!)!! + 0! + 0!) \times \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} $
>  $ 351 = ((11!)!! + 0! + 0!) \times \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} + 0! $
>  $ 352 = (11!)! \times .1 - 1000 $
>  $ 353 = (11!)! \times .1 - 0! - (1 + 0! + 0!)! $
>  $ 354 = (11!)! \times .1 - (1 + 0! + 0!)! $
>  $ 355 = ((1 + 0! + 0!)!)! \times .1 - 101 $
>  $ 356 = (11!)! \times .1 - 100 $
>  $ 357 = ((1 + 0! + 0!)!)! \times .1 - 11 $
>  $ 358 = (11!)! \times .1 - 1 - 0! $
>  $ 359 = (11!)! \times .1 - 1 $
>  $ 360 = (11!)! \times .1 $
>  $ 361 = (11!)! \times .1 + 1 $
>  $ 362 = (11!)! \times .1 + 1 + 0! $
>  $ 363 = ((1 + 0! + 0!)!)! \times .1 + 11 $
>  $ 364 = (11!)! \times .1 + 100 $
>  $ 365 = ((1 + 0! + 0!)!)! \times .1 + 101 $
>  $ 366 = (11!)! \times .1 + (1 + 0! + 0!)! $
>  $ 367 = (11!)! \times .1 + 0! + (1 + 0! + 0!)! $
>  $ 368 = 100!! + (11!)! \times .1 $
>  $ 369 = (100!!)!! - (11! - 0!)!! $
>  $ 370 = (100!!)!! + 0! - (11! - 0!)!! $
>  $ 371 = (100! + (11!)!) \times .1 - 0! $
>  $ 372 = (100! + ((1 + 0! + 0!)!)!) \times .1 $
>  $ 373 = (100!!)!! - \sqrt{((11! - 0!)! + 0!)} $
>  $ 374 = (100!!)!! - 1010 $
>  $ 375 = (100! + 0!) \times (11! - 0!)!! $
>  $ 376 = (100!!)!! - (11 + 0!)!! $
>  $ 377 = (100!!)!! - 0! - 11! $
>  $ 378 = (100!!)!! - (1 + 0! + 0!)! $
>  $ 379 = (100!!)!! - 101 $
>  $ 380 = (100!!)!! - 100 $
>  $ 381 = (100!!)!! - 11 $
>  $ 382 = (100!!)!! - 0! - 0! $
>  $ 383 = (100!!)!! - 0! $
>  $ 384 = (100!!)!! $
>  $ 385 = (100!!)!! + 0! $
>  $ 386 = (100!!)!! + 0! + 0! $
>  $ 387 = (100!!)!! + 11 $
>  $ 388 = (100!!)!! + 100 $
>  $ 389 = (100!!)!! + 101 $
>  $ 390 = 11! + ((1 + 0! + 0! + 0!)!!)!! $
>  $ 391 = (100!!)!! + 0! + 11! $
>  $ 392 = (100!!)!! + (11 + 0!)!! $
>  $ 393 = ((11 + 0!)!!)!! + 1001 $
>  $ 394 = (100!!)!! + 1010 $
>  $ 395 = (100!!)!! + \sqrt{((11! - 0!)! + 0!)} $
>  $ 396 = (100!!)!! + 1100 $
>  $ 397 = (100!!)!! + 1101 $
>  $ 398 = (100!!)!! - 0! + (11! - 0!)!! $
>  $ 399 = (100!!)!! + (11! - 0!)!! $
>  $ 400 = (100!!)!! + 0! + (11! - 0!)!! $
>  $ 401 = (100!!)!! + 101!! + 1 + 0! $
>  $ 402 = (100!!)!! + \sqrt{((11!)! \times .1 + 0!)} - 0! $
>  $ 403 = (100!!)!! + \sqrt{((11!)! \times .1 + 0!)} $
>  $ 404 = (11!)! \times .1001 - 0! $
>  $ 405 = (11!)! \times .1001 $
>  $ 406 = (11!)! \times .1001 + 0! $
>  $ 407 = 100! - 0! + ((11 + 0!)!!)!! $
>  $ 408 = 100! + ((11 + 0!)!!)!! $
>  $ 409 = 100! + 0! + ((11 + 0!)!!)!! $

Comment: You know, the $\sqrt{((11!-0!)!+0!}$ to get $11$ (decimal) is cute, but unless you're short on $1$s you could just use $(100!!)!! + 1011$ for $395$. :) A ton of other nice tools in here though, especially for $11$ and $19$. Really would love a $13$ but that's harder...

Comment: You have a spare $0$ in $350$, so $\pm 0!$ to get $349,351$. Same for $402$ from $403$, $347$ from $348$, $340$ from $341$, and $327, 331$ from $329$.

Comment: Also, adding 1 to 338's expression gives 339. Alternatively, 339 = 1101^(0!+0!)/.1+0!

Comment: @EricSnyder my generator isn't optimised yet.

Comment: 332 = $ (100!!)!! - (11!)!! - 100 $,  
333 = $ (100!!)!! - (11!)!! - 10 - 0! $,  
346 = $ \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} ^ {11} + 0! + 0! + 0! $,  
349 = $ \sqrt{((11!)!! + 0!)} ^ {11} + (0! + 0! + 0!)! $,  
401 = $ (100!!)!!+0!+(11!−0!)!! + 1 $

Comment: @JoelRondeau thanks for the update - only 326 is unsolved in this range.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, I've been optimizing some of the numbers to get an extra 0 or 1. Thought I had 326, but math error.

Comment: 326 = (11!*11)^(0!+0!)+0!+0!

Comment: Oh, that's very nice work @isaacg. With a better choice for $324$ as well.

Answer (score -2):

A bit of lateral thinking:

> All numbers can *technically* be made using this equation:$$\frac{0}{0}+0+0*1*1*1*1$$ $\frac{0}{0}$ will get you any number you want.

Comment: Not my DV, but the lack of definition of $ \frac{0}{0} $ is about whether the quotient is $0$ ($0$ divided by anything), $1$ (any number divided by itself) or $ \infty $ (any number divided by $0$) – not some arbitrary value.

Comment: There are better ways to do "all numbers" without resorting to $0/0$, using logarithms and square roots. Adapting from the four fours problem gives this, which I think works: $$n=-\sqrt{10}\frac{\log\left[\left(\log\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{10}}}}_{n}\right)/\log10\right]}{\log10}$$

Comment: Eric Snyder, You should post it as an actual answer if it does work.

Comment: Based on the given rules, I'm not sure if the usage of 'log' is allowed.

Comment: @Mike It's definitely WAY outside the given rules. But it's at least mathematical, as opposed to $0/0$.

Comment: @EricSnyder from a few trials (*n* = 2, 3, 5, 7 and 11) the first term $-\sqrt{10}$ should be just $-$ (minus).

Comment: The only thing outside the rules is **log**. Apart from that it works (subject to the previous comment) for natural numbers. It's amazing!

Comment: It's just copied from the Wiki article on the four fours problem, with $10$ in place of $4$. It's a well-known "solution," and not my own. And @WeatherVane, you're right, I think the move from $4$ to $2$ removes the need for that $\sqrt2$.

Comment: ok @EricSnyder. Still cool though

Comment: @EricSnyder The heart of Puzzling.SE is finding elegant solutions with just enough of a twist that they're not immediately obvious. It's a pity that logs were not included in the question. Otherwise, your four-fours adaptation would be a model answer to the OP's puzzle.

Comment: @Lawrence and without the leading $\sqrt{01}$ there are only 3 zeros, 3 ones, no addition, no powers and no factorials.

Comment: @Lawrence Sure, but I want to make sure in this case that "finding" meant "going to Wikipedia for a formula I knew was there." So, credit only for bringing that formula here. :)

Comment: @WeatherVane Unfortunately, l'Hospital put the lie to that statement: a function with a naïve derivative of 0/0 at a point can have a true derivative at that point of any value within the function's domain, plus infinity